# for each loop or array

Tags: php, html

I have a page that displays profile info and it is joined by 2 tables..

Table1 - user

---

### id      -     email       -   username

```
1      | email |   bill
```

Table2 - images

---

### image id  |    id    |  cover_image

```
1        |     1    |   image1.jpg
2        |     1    |   image2.jpg
3        |     1    |   image3.jpg
4        |     1    |   image4.jpg
5        |     1    |   image5.jpg
```

I have everything displaying, I am not sure accomplish the ability for multiple images list.

if user id is 1 when they upload a image it also will insert a id of 1

so if the user has 5 images I want it to display like

```
<img src="images/gallery/$cover_img"></a>
<img src="images/gallery/$cover_img"></a>
<img src="images/gallery/$cover_img"></a>
<img src="images/gallery/$cover_img"></a>
<img src="images/gallery/$cover_img"></a>
```

but right now it only will shows 1 of the images

```
$db = dbconnect();
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `images` ON images.id = users.id GROUP BY users.id');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: How do get the data?Where's the code?

Comment: where is your query and code ?

Comment: I added my query code above but its not the query code I don't think

Comment: What is your table structures, and where is code for displaying images?

Comment: the code for displaying is the problem when I echo out the above code stated with $cover_image only one shows because the image code needs to be in an array

Answer (score 0):

No need to use join and group by query you can also use foreach loop for fetching value.

```
<?php  
 try {
        $sql1='select * from  users' ;
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql1) as $row)
             {
                $uid=$row['id']; 
                    $sql2='select * from images where id='.$uid.'' ;
                        foreach ($dbh->query($sql2) as $row2)
                         {
                             $images=$row2['cover_image'];
                         }
             }
               $dbh = null;
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo "Some Exception Occured " . $ex;
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: A `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` will use *far* less resources than the solution you propose; **it will also take at least three times as long**.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your query like as below for getting proper data, that you want.

Here is the `MySQL query` for getting Data

> **Example 1 :** Getting All Users Images

```
SELECT
 user.email,
 user.bill,
 images.id,
 images.cover_image
FROM user
INNER JOIN images ON user.id=images.id
ORDER BY images.id ASC
```

> **Example 2 :** Getting Single User Images

```
SELECT
 user.email,
 user.bill,
 images.id,
 images.cover_image
FROM user
INNER JOIN images ON user.id=images.id
WHERE user.id= 1 #Here 1 is the user ID
```

> Here is an **Example** using `mysqli`

**`users`** Table

```
+----------+-----------------+----------+
|    id    |      email      |  bill    |
+----------+-----------------+----------+
|    1     | email@email.com |  5000    |
+----------+-----------------+----------+
```

**`images`** Table

```
+----------+-----------------+----------------+
|    id    |      user_id    |  cover_image   |
+----------+-----------------+----------------+
|    1     |         1       |  image1.jpg    |
+----------+-----------------+----------------+
|    2     |         1       |  image2.jpg    |
+----------+-----------------+----------------+
|    ...   |        ...      |      ...       |
+----------+-----------------+----------------+
```

**`PHP and MySQL`** Codes using `mysqli`

```
#$db = dbconnect();
$db = new mysqli("HOSTNAME", "USER", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE_NAME");

if($db->connect_error){
  die("$db->connect_errno: $db->connect_error");
}

$sql = '
    SELECT
        users.email,
        users.bill,
        images.user_id,
        images.cover_image
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN images ON users.id=images.user_id
    ORDER BY images.id ASC';

 $stmt   = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

**`Display Images`** From `$result`

```
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ #Get every row as an Associative array?>
    <img src="images/gallery/<?php echo $row['cover_image'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['cover_image'] ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ahh! Ok, Are you using `PDO` for getting Data? @Case

Comment: I updated the answer  using `PDO` for you! Check it @Case

Comment: @summon Sarker http://bodyelectrictattoo.com/our-team/ see how his profiles display with a list of images for user profile this is what I am trying to accomplish the images need to echo out in a list

Comment: Okay! I just give you an example by depend on your question. Which functions/methods you are using? mysql? mysqli? or Other? @Case

Comment: mysqli prepared stmt

Comment: @ Sumon Sarker it still does not work it gives same result  it echos user profile everytime a new image is added so user one will end up with 5 profiles for 5 images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139401/discussion-between-case-and-sumon-sarker).

Answer (score -1):

To accomplish that you will need to replace the LEFT JOIN with RIGHT JOIN you your mysql query.